# How to handle Publish Confirm in RabbitMQ .NET

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

I'm new in RabbitMQ. i need to know how to Publish Confirm in .NET because i need to send and receive response from client/server. The problem is i dont know how to correctly handle publish Confirm.

```
 channel.ConfirmSelect();
 var outstandingConfirms = new ConcurrentDictionary<ulong, string>();

            void cleanOutstandingConfirms(ulong sequenceNumber, bool multiple)
            {
                if (multiple)
                {
                    var confirmed = outstandingConfirms.Where(k => k.Key <= sequenceNumber);
                    foreach (var entry in confirmed)
                        outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(entry.Key, out _);
                }
                else
                    outstandingConfirms.TryRemove(sequenceNumber, out _);
            }

            channel.BasicAcks += (sender, ea) => cleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
            channel.BasicNacks += (sender, ea) =>
            {
                outstandingConfirms.TryGetValue(ea.DeliveryTag, out string body);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message with body {body} has been nack-ed. Sequence number: {ea.DeliveryTag}, multiple: {ea.Multiple}");
                cleanOutstandingConfirms(ea.DeliveryTag, ea.Multiple);
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < MESSAGE_COUNT; i++)
            {
                var body = i.ToString();
                outstandingConfirms.TryAdd(channel.NextPublishSeqNo, i.ToString());
                channel.BasicPublish("",
                routingKey: "****",
                basicProperties: null,
                body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)); 
            }
```

I need to receive response from client server after message already arrived.
like "Success Add Data"

i get this from the rabbitmq documentation(Handling Publisher Confirms Asynchronously). But i dont know how it is work. Im welcome for disscuss and learn from you guys. Correct me if im wrong please, Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly it is that you need but right now, this code will publish and the callbacks (`BasicAcks`/`BasicNacks`) will fire when the server confirms.

Comment: @JohanP hmm im new in rabbitmq, the condition right now that i already consume from publisher but i dont know what i do is right or not, About BasicAck or BasickNack in my server confirms right now i dont know to handle with BasicACKs pr basicNack. what i already do right now is just consume and do something then give messase "Success" to producer.

Comment: @JohanP can u help me? i have a case that i need to make sure my message from producer that arrive successfully and get response from client like "Success Add Data". how i can do it?